# How does `derivative_account_id` create an `AccountId`?

Tags: rust, accountid

In the Utility pallet there is a function:

```rust
/// Derive a derivative account ID from the owner account and the sub-account index.
pub fn derivative_account_id(who: T::AccountId, index: u16) -> T::AccountId {
    let entropy = (b"modlpy/utilisuba", who, index).using_encoded(blake2_256);
    Decode::decode(&mut TrailingZeroInput::new(entropy.as_ref()))
        .expect("infinite length input; no invalid inputs for type; qed")
}
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1cc2a007290ce32314a17e7d03af7b986e0630dc/frame/utility/src/lib.rs#L512-L517

`using_encoded()` converts `(b"modlpy/utilisuba", who, index)` to a slice, encodes it, then it invokes `blake2_256` on the slice.

`TrailingZeroInput` adds zeros to the end of this byte array.

`Decode::decode()` deserializes the value.

But what actually converts the deserialized value into an `AccountId`?

I see that `AccountId` is defined in the node primitives:

```rust
/// Some way of identifying an account on the chain. We intentionally make it equivalent
/// to the public key of our transaction signing scheme.
pub type AccountId = <<Signature as Verify>::Signer as IdentifyAccount>::AccountId;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`frame_system::Config::AccountId` requires `Decode + Encode`.

And in your pallet, `trait Config: frame_system::Config`.

So, `T::AccountId` has these functions.

Just treat it as a codec object.

You don't need to care about the `primitives::AccountId`. `frame_system::Config::AccountId` will guarantee it has the `decode` function.

---

And if you want to know how the decoding works:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232644/converting-between-accountid32-and-accountid-in-substrate

---

Let me give you a re-implementation as an example.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=04784c805dfd38620228144a48f6abc3

```rs
use std::marker::PhantomData;

type AccountId = u8;

trait Decode {
    fn decode(bytes: [u8; 1]) -> Self;
}
impl Decode for AccountId {
    fn decode(bytes: [u8; 1]) -> Self {
        u8::from_be_bytes(bytes)
    }
}

trait FrameSystemConfig {
    type AccountId: Decode;
}
trait PalletUtilityConfig: FrameSystemConfig {}

struct PalletUtility<T>(PhantomData<T>);
impl<T> PalletUtility<T> 
where
    T: PalletUtilityConfig
{
    fn bytes2account(bytes: [u8; 1]) -> T::AccountId {
        Decode::decode(bytes)
    }
}

struct Runtime;
impl FrameSystemConfig for Runtime {
    type AccountId = AccountId;
}
impl PalletUtilityConfig for Runtime {}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", <PalletUtility<Runtime>>::bytes2account([0]));
}
```

Comment: Still not clear how Rust goes from bytes to T::AccountId. Is there an implicit conversion?

Comment: Updated my answer. This is just a Rust question.